# Properties strategy in a webapp aplication

Tags: jsf, web-applications, properties, seam3

I have a webapp written in JSF, CDI and Seam 3 and I have a properties file with all strings that are rendered in all the views, however, I wonder if it's better to have a properties file for each one of the views or have only one with a lots of values.

Are there any best practises for having a well structured properties file?? Having one properties per view is a good "properties design"?? 
I thing that having one properties per view means that when you delete one view or refactor something you have to change a lot of files (properties), if you're application is ready for displaying many languages... probably it's better having only one with all the strings...

Any suggestions??

thanks

Comment: http://webmoli.com/2008/05/20/jsf-best-practices/ here, says that is a good practise "Keep resource bundle name and xhtml name as same. Example SearchUsers.xhtml and SearchUsers.properties"

Answer (score 1):

If goal is multilanguage support. I think you must have one file for each language.

Comment: yes one file for each language, but my question was if it's good to have one properties per view ...